# How to Replace Bad Words in a Comment with Asterisks Using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hope All Of You are Fine.

I have a File in Of Bad Words, I want to Replace Bad Words in a Comments with Asterisks.

Bad Words URL : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/e8e6798137b1ff4836d6ebcf73fef7dc/raw/415dfc8cbab13fa6033fbb4d4ce9eae7a9dbe7cd/Bad_Words.txt

I wrote Below Lines Of Code But It's not Working :(

Kindly Help.

```
<?php
$abusive_words = file_get_contents('Bad_Words.txt');
$abusive_words = explode("\n", $abusive_words);
$input_string = 'Catch that bastard, Idiot .... !!';
$fixed = str_ireplace($abusive_words,'*****',$input_string);
echo "Input String <br> $input_string <br><br><hr><br>Input String Fixed <br> $fixed";
?>
```

Comment: what is not working? are you using windows file endings? \r\n? Whats inside the abusive_words array? did you debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be cases where whitespace is appended to the array element($abusive_words) while retrieving it from the text file. str_ireplace() might not be able to get perfect match due to these whitespaces. So its always better to trim the array elements before proceeding further especially for comparison.

array_map() and trim is what you need.

$abusive_words = array_map('trim', $abusive_words);

Do this before passing array to str_ireplace()

Answer (score 1):

Here I am sharing example where we just have to set replace with character and it will replace characters of string.

for ex. Bitch will replace with ***** (5 stars) and for crap it will show **** (4 starts).

```
$abusive_words = ['bitch', 'crap', 'bastard'];
$input_string = 'Catch that bastard, Idiot .... !!';
$replaceWith = '*';

$replace = array();
$replace['a'] = '(a|a\.|a\-|4|@|Á|á|À|Â|à|Â|â|Ä|ä|Ã|ã|Å|å|α|Δ|Λ|λ)';
$replace['b'] = '(b|b\.|b\-|8|\|3|ß|Β|β)';
$replace['c'] = '(c|c\.|c\-|Ç|ç|¢|€|<|\(|{|©)';
$replace['d'] = '(d|d\.|d\-|&part;|\|\)|Þ|þ|Ð|ð)';
$replace['e'] = '(e|e\.|e\-|3|€|È|è|É|é|Ê|ê|∑)';
$replace['f'] = '(f|f\.|f\-|ƒ)';
$replace['g'] = '(g|g\.|g\-|6|9)';
$replace['h'] = '(h|h\.|h\-|Η)';
$replace['i'] = '(i|i\.|i\-|!|\||\]\[|]|1|∫|Ì|Í|Î|Ï|ì|í|î|ï)';
$replace['j'] = '(j|j\.|j\-)';
$replace['k'] = '(k|k\.|k\-|Κ|κ)';
$replace['l'] = '(l|1\.|l\-|!|\||\]\[|]|£|∫|Ì|Í|Î|Ï)';
$replace['m'] = '(m|m\.|m\-)';
$replace['n'] = '(n|n\.|n\-|η|Ν|Π)';
$replace['o'] = '(o|o\.|o\-|0|Ο|ο|Φ|¤|°|ø)';
$replace['p'] = '(p|p\.|p\-|ρ|Ρ|¶|þ)';
$replace['q'] = '(q|q\.|q\-)';
$replace['r'] = '(r|r\.|r\-|®)';
$replace['s'] = '(s|s\.|s\-|5|\$|§)';
$replace['t'] = '(t|t\.|t\-|Τ|τ)';
$replace['u'] = '(u|u\.|u\-|υ|µ)';
$replace['v'] = '(v|v\.|v\-|υ|ν)';
$replace['w'] = '(w|w\.|w\-|ω|ψ|Ψ)';
$replace['x'] = '(x|x\.|x\-|Χ|χ)';
$replace['y'] = '(y|y\.|y\-|¥|γ|ÿ|ý|Ÿ|Ý)';
$replace['z'] = '(z|z\.|z\-|Ζ)';

$replacement = array();
$whiteListCount = count($abusive_words);

for ($x = 0; $x < $whiteListCount; $x++) {
    $replacement[$x] = str_repeat($replaceWith, strlen($abusive_words[$x]));
    $abusive_words[$x] = '/' . str_ireplace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $abusive_words[$x]) . '/i';
}
echo preg_replace($abusive_words, $replacement, $input_string);
```

You can move main logic bunch of codes in separate function and used in any files where you want to replace bad words from content of any length.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $abusive_words = file_get_contents('Bad_Words.txt');
   $abusive_words = explode("\n", $abusive_words); // here you got an array of strings
   $input_string = 'Catch that bastard, Idiot .... !!';

   $fixed=$input_string;
   foreach ($abusive_words as $ab_word) // then you need to use loop to get each element of array
      $fixed = str_ireplace($ab_word,'*****',$fixed); //replacing any array string to *****

   echo "Input String <br> $input_string <br><br><hr><br>Input String  Fixed <br> $fixed";
 ?>
```

Comment: Not Working Bro.

Comment: Still Not Working Bro